# Escape Single Quote Twice in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I come across the situation that I need to use the escape quote twice. Specifically, I need to put an variable in javascript function with single quotes, but the variable itself also has single quotes. Details can be seen below, the problem line is the one with class "tile_name":

```
template = '' +
    '<div name="'+$("#add_tags :selected").text()+'" class="tile" id="newsCat_gp" >' +
        '<span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = \'none\';" class="closebtn">&times;</span>' +
        '<div class="tile__name"><b><font size="2px">'+$("#add_tags :selected").text()+'</b></font>  <a id="newCat__'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+'img" style="text-align: right; float: right;" href="javascript:toggle5(\'newCat__\'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+\'\', \'img\', \'newCat__\'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+\'img\');"><img src=  "{% static '/img/minus.png' %}"></a> </div>' +
        '<div class="tile__list" id="newCat__'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+'" style="display: block;"></div>' +
    '</div>';
```

I want the results is

```
\'newCat__\'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+\'\'
```

becomes

```
'newCat__'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+' '
```

like what in the tile_list class, and finally give the results of 
     newCat__20,

where 20 is held by `$("#idx_newsCat").text()`.

Could anyone has the idea? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to not escape ' where you concat string

```
javascript:toggle5(\'newCat__'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+'\', \'img\', \'newCat__'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+'img\');
```

Comment: so, it seems like once a block with quotes escape, the system will not care what is within the block and we can write the syntax as normal, right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```js
var template = '' +
    '<div name="'+$("#add_tags :selected").text()+'" class="tile" id="newsCat_gp" >' +
        '<span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = \'none\';" class="closebtn">&times;</span>' +
        '<div class="tile__name"><b><font size="2px">'+$("#add_tags :selected").text()+'</b></font>  <a id="newCat__'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+'img" style="text-align: right; float: right;" href="javascript:toggle5(\'newCat__\'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+\'\', \'img\', \'newCat__\'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+\'img\');"><img src=  "{% static \'/img/minus.png\' %}"></a> </div>' +
        '<div class="tile__list" id="newCat__'+$("#idx_newsCat").text()+'" style="display: block;"></div>' +
    '</div>';

$('body').append(template);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```